# Springboot REST context mapping - multiple applications

Tags: spring-boot

I have 3 different springboot REST applications related to order - product, manage, location.
Context mapping at the moment for 3 applications.

```
Product application has so many REST entities and controller has mapping like this
 context is /product and controller mapping is /information and many others
```

Manage and location applications got controllers with mappings

```
 manage app context is /manage and controller is /user and many others  
 location app context is /location and controller is /config and many others
```

I would like to achieve below mapping for 3 different springboot applications.
Desired mapping respectively to above one:

```
for product application context /order/{id}/product/ and controller is /information  
same for manage and location apps /order/{id}/manage  
/order/{id}/location
```

Any help would be great. Appreciate your time.

Comment: I think only your `@RequestMapping` annotation is going to change with value field having `order/{id}` prefixed to it. Also I hope I understand your question correctly ?

Comment: @rdj7 thank you. I dont want each controller to have total context. I want context to be like order/{id}/product. Controller will have simple mapping like - /information for information controller inside product application.

Comment: Sorry, I am little unclear about what you are asking, can you please edit your question so everyone understands clearly. May be you cab include some code clocks or some more details.

Comment: @rdj7 thanks for your time.  just updated the question. Hope that makes bit more sense.